# Can't connect to Socket IO with SSL

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Server:

```
// Load libraries
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

// The server options
var srvAddress = '123.123.123.123';
var srvPort = 8888;
var srvOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ssl/cert-ca.crt')
};

// Create a Basic server and response
var app = https.createServer(srvOptions, function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Online...');
});

// Create the Socket.io Server over the HTTPS Server
var io = socketio.listen(app, srvAddress);

// Now listen in the specified Port
app.listen(srvPort, srvAddress);
```

Client:

```
var socket = require("socket.io-client").connect('https://123.123.123.123:8888', {secure: true});
```

But client don't connect to server. I tried http instead of https, but the same result.
Server works fine. Without ssl certificate connection works. When try to open via web, then all works too.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful (had the same problem today) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449234/socket-io-cant-connect-through-https

Comment: Not the same problem, I can't connect from socket.io-client, but for example the SocketIO client for iOS connects to the server