# Node script wont run through https

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I have a problem, my website now have a SSL certificate but now my node script doesn't run.

node.js

```
var cs = require('./chatServer.js');
var ns = require('./notificationServer.js');
ns.start();
cs.start();
```

notificationServer.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3002,{log:false});
var sys = require('util');
var moment = require('moment');
function notificationStart(){
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
        // my code
    });
}
exports.start=notificationStart;
```

chatServer.js

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3003,{log:false});
var sys = require('util');
var DBWrapper = require('node-dbi').DBWrapper; 
var DBExpr = require('node-dbi').DBExpr;
function chatStart()
{
    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) 
    {
        // my code
    });
}
exports.start = chatStart;
```

index.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mydomain.com:3003/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web/controllers/js/myChat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var mychat = new myChat();
        mychat.init('name','channel', 't', true);
    });
</script>
```

myChat.js

```
function myChat(){
    var _this = this;
    this.chatServer;
    this.init = function(user, room, type, announce, publicChannel,window){
        _this.chatServer = io.connect('https://mydomain.com:3003');
        _this.chatServer.on('connect',function(){
            _this.chatServer.emit('adduser', user, room, type);
        });
    };
}
```

in the terminal:

> node /my/path/node.js

When the website was HTTP, the node.js worked, but now doesn't work with HTTPS
Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you describe the actual issue a bit more? In what way does it not work?

Comment: [with HTTP](http://bit.ly/1gHSf6N), [with HTTPS](http://bit.ly/1kGA1GE) @AndrewBarber

Comment: You posted the same link twice there.

Comment: Sorry, edited link @AndrewBarber

Comment: Cool; got it. Looks like your HTTPS simply isn't listening, perhaps? There's no response at all from what I can see in that.

Comment: I read a little about nodejs, I stumbled upon [this](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html), but not if it will be the solution for my case

Comment: Wait; silly question: I notice on your screen shot it's connecting to port 3002, but your script above says 3003. Could that be it?

Comment: What happens is that the screenshots are from the production server and the development machine, respectively. that's why the variation of ports (Currently the production server is HTTP, but is making the migration to HTTPS, I could not finish this migration for this inconvenience)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your socket.io is configured to work on the http protocol, not on the https protocol. I'm pretty sure if you change (in myChat.js) :

```
io.connect('https://mydomain.com:3003');
```

by :

```
io.connect('http://mydomain.com:3003');
```

It will work.

(Check your port too)

In order to configure socket.io with the HTTPS protocol, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449234/socket-io-cant-connect-through-https).

I found that on Google : http://chrislarson.me/blog/ssl-nodejs-express-and-socketio

Comment: When using HTTP, the browser will throw an error on the console that says: 
It has blocked active content mixed load "http://200.6.158.101:3003/socket.io/1/?t=1396971085155"

Comment: It should be because of your page is in https and you use socket.io in http. Did you try to configure socket.io with the https protocol ?

Comment: I found that on Google : http://chrislarson.me/blog/ssl-nodejs-express-and-socketio