# Socket.io chat server not presenting SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, websocket, socket.io

A (simple) chat is part of an application I've created a while back. Today I'm switching the website from http to https. Therefore I also have to SSL my Socket.io chat socket, otherwise browsers will whine.

For some reason though my chatserver isn't presenting any certificate at all. Using openssl on linux confirms this:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.subdomain.tld:1337 -servername my.subdomain.tld -ssl3
```

returns

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140136057653064:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1436357417
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I obviously replaced the domains. The port is actually 1337 and the server uses SNI so I believe I have to use the -servername argument?

My Node server (simplified):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/home/ssl_certificates/my_subdomain_tld.key').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/home/ssl_certificates/my_subdomain_tld.crt').toString();
var ca = fs.readFileSync('/home/ssl_certificates/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt').toString();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1337, {key: privateKey, cert: certificate, 'ca': ca});
```

The certificates do exist at that location and they are valid (double checked). How can I go about debugging this? Why is Socket.IO not presenting a certificate?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449234/socket-io-cant-connect-through-https

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier keeping socket.io behind an actual webserver like nginx? Let nginx handle the certificates.

Comment: No. I don't want to setup a webserver for a chatserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in [docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#listen) listen is instance method of Server class. 
Instantiate https server first, attach certificates to it, and then pass it to Server() constructor.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('~/.certs/my-sub.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('~/.certs/my-sub.crt')
};

var app = https.createServer(options);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(1337);
```

There is a documented ability to start server using socket.io itself described [here](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events).Options that can be passed to io's [Server()](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server%28opts:object%29) method are listed in [engine.io docs](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1). It seems like you can't attach certificates to it.

Comment: Hah, interesting! But it works! Thanks alot, much appreciated :)

Comment: got me started - but if one requires express too - look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11745114/3022387 … essentially:  https.createServer(credential_options,express_app)