# SSL Socket.io/ExpressJS server

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, socket.io

I'm building a SocketIO server, and I've managed to get it working through HTTP. But I would like to use it over HTTPS, and here is my problem.

I can't find any documentation on how to do that : it's either not working or outdated.

Here is my code :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'pim',
    port     : 8889
});
var cors = require('cors');
var parse = require('url-parse');
var connected_users = [];

app.use(cors());

connection.connect();

http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Websockets server listening on port 3000');
    setInterval(function() {
        connected_users.forEach(function(user) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM notification WHERE is_read = 0 AND user_id = ' + connection.escape(user.user_id), function(err, rows) {
                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    rows.forEach(function(row) {
                        io.to(user.session_id).emit('notification', row);
                    });

                    /* Updating notification is treated after not to slow down the notification events */
                    rows.forEach(function(row) {
                        connection.query('UPDATE notification SET is_read = 1 WHERE id = ' + row.id + ' AND user_id = ' + connection.escape(user.user_id));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }, 5000);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    var url = parse(socket.handshake.url, true);
    var user_id = url.query.user_id;
    var session_id = socket.id;

    if (undefined !== user_id && 'null' !== user_id) {
        connected_users.push({
            session_id: session_id,
            user_id: user_id
        });
        console.log('A user with ID ' + user_id + ' connected.');
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
        connected_users.forEach(function(user, index) {
            if (user.session_id === session_id) {
                connected_users.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
        console.log('A user with ID ' + user_id + ' disconnected.');
    });
});
```

Could you give me a solution to do that ? Or an up-to-date tutorial ? I wasn't able to find one...

Comment: here is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449234/socket-io-cant-connect-through-https

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, it solved my problem... Thanks a lot.